# What is the default diskspace that URLCache.shared instance has

Tags: ios, nsurlcache

Is it necessary to assign diskspace when I use URLCache.share instance? What is the default value that it has?

Answer (score 2):

@ScottZhu's answer in Swift:

```
URLCache.shared.memoryCapacity
URLCache.shared.diskCapacity
URLCache.shared.currentMemoryUsage
URLCache.shared.currentDiskUsage
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your default cache size in bytes:

```
po URLSession.shared.configuration.urlCache?.currentMemoryUsage
- some : 1859

po URLSession.shared.configuration.urlCache?.memoryCapacity
- some : 512000

po URLSession.shared.configuration.urlCache?.diskCapacity
- some : 10000000

po URLSession.shared.configuration.urlCache?.currentDiskUsage
- some : 98408
```

Different devices might have different cache sizes, but that's the way to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use it.

[From Apple Docs:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcache/1413377-shared)

> Applications that do not have special caching requirements or
>   constraints should find the default shared cache instance acceptable.
>   An application with more specific needs can create a custom URLCache
>   object and set it as the shared cache instance using setShared(_:).
>   The application should do so before any calls to this method.

If you don't want to use caching set it explicitly to nil.

```
URLCache.shared = {
        URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
}()
```